# reset user password

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a server which has machines...

I have an administrator and multiple users... these are all windows users and not present in the databse.

How do i reset the user password.... i log in using the administrator and provide the username that needs to be reset..

I tried

```
 string newPassword;

 u = Membership.GetUser(UsernameTextBox.Text, false);
```

but this does not work...

any suggestions... thanks

Code to add users:

```
 DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
            DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add(username, "user");
            NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
            NewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", description });
            NewUser.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Did you set up the supporting asp.net membership database table structure and configure your membership provider prior to trying to use these features?

Comment: i use DirectoryEntry for adding a user...

Comment: It sounds like you're using Windows authentication, not Forms Authentication. Is that true?

Comment: ahh...now it's clear as mud...learn more about asp.net membership here http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Comment: hey jim.. thanks for the link.. but i cannot use forms authentication alone.. i use a combination of forms and windows authentication.... so now my question is if i can create the windows user without modifying anythng and using AD why cant i reset the password...

Comment: I've only used the membership API with the underlying database so I don't know about your specific case.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx looks like it has some info on hooking up AD and the Membership API.  I think you're trying to mix some apples and oranges which is great if you want to make some fruit salad but not so great if you want to reset a users password :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it done by this methid.. it works thanks for the answers though

```
DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
DirectoryEntry HostedUser = AD.Children.Find(hostedUserName, "user");

string password = new HostedGuiAddMachines().CreateRandomPassword(8);
HostedUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
HostedUser.Close();
AD.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
string username = "user";
string password = "newpassword";
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username);
mu.ChangePassword(mu.ResetPassword(), password);
```

if you have in your web.config requiresQuestionAnswer="true", you will get an error when you try and reset the password.

Comment: An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. The SQL error number is 5123 and the SqlException message is: CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF'.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
Creating the ASPNETDB_1f5ebd767bfd48a9b513cf18197b312d database...

Comment: but you can create users, return a list of users and iterate over them?  You only see an error when you're trying to reset a users password?  InstallCommon.sql installs membership related services and if you're already up and running, you shouldn't see it.  Do you have read/write permission on the app_data folder?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the [ResetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d94bdzz2.aspx) method. To reset to a known password you can use something like this:

```
MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(user_name);
bool bPasswordChanged = false;
bPasswordChanged = currentUser.ChangePassword(currentUser.ResetPassword(), new_password);
```

Comment: An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. The SQL error number is 5123 and the SqlException message is: CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. Creating the ASPNETDB_1f5ebd767bfd48a9b513cf18197b312d database...

Comment: happens when u call Membership.GetUser() function